# tow to get updateTime function on videogular-2

Tags: angular, video-streaming

how to get vg-update-time function on videogular2 in angular 5
i using html

```
<video *ngIf="url" id="video"class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-16-9"controls preload="auto">
  <source [src]="url" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get updates when the current time changes, you can use the `timeUpdate` subscription on the `vgApi` api

```
vgApi.subscriptions.timeUpdate.subscribe(data => {

  let currentTime = data.srcElement.currentTime;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using videogular2, you can track played duration:

```
onPlayerReady(api: VgAPI) {
  this.api = api;
  this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.loadedMetadata.subscribe(
    ($event) => {
      console.log("API  " + this.api.duration);  // Total duration
    });

  this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.timeUpdate.subscribe(
    ($event) => {
      console.log("API current time: ", this.api.currentTime); //current time
    });
 }
```